# How to properly round this formula?

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

The other day I asked a question in help for writing a certain formula for a calculation sheet. This is the answer someone gave me for the right column:

```
 CEILING(K5/4)
```

Then for the left column, I came up with this:

```
 CEILING((J12/2) -3)
```

The problem is, when the number inputed in K5/J12 becomes too high, the result calculated rounds up by a lot. This is because I'm using both calculations together, like so:

```
 =CEILING(K5/4) + CEILING((J12/2) -3) + 10
```

At some point the formula starts rounding things up by two whole numbers! So where the result should be 20, it ends up as 22. I would really appreciate it if anyone could help me with this!! I really don't understand how these formulas work.. so any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: *"The problem is, when the number inputed..."* and further down *"At some point the formula starts..."*. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: There are flaws in both tables in your question. The table on the right should be groups of four but "5-9" (and each subsequent element) is a group of 5. The table of the left begins as groups of two (9-10), but changes to groups of three (11-13), groups of four (17-20), and groups of five (21-25); yet your formula is designed for groups of two.